# Codeignaiter 2.2.0 Severity: Notice --> Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: codeigniter

```
is_object($this->data['row'])

bool(true) 

$this->data['row']->product_id
```

but i get

> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object

what i'm doing wrong

Comment: show your output of $this->data['row'];

Comment: $this->db->get()->row() why is in json

Comment: it is object but problem is with this parenthesis [] with each key that is why you get error

Comment: can you show your model where u retrieving your data

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db7aa82cb36897495a9c021f707fe84f66fa23a1

Comment: if you are retrieving it from single row then u should use $this->data instead of $this->data['row']

Comment: how you are assigning return data  to $this->data pls show

Comment: the same thing Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: are you sure it is from $this->db->get()->row() not from $this->db->get();

Comment: how you are assigning return data to $this->data pls show

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ed5e07395ab7a230f43ae1670437bad9bbc9623

Comment: can you show your output of var_dump($this->data) ? u can also use print_r($this->data)

Comment: nothing helps  problem is only on $this->db->get()->row() print_r($this->data) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/510ff61fbde4239957a1a43bf11cb9abf670d0cd

Answer (score 0):

I think you have first check, data type of variable:
convert into object if datatype is an array:

```
if(is_array($this->data['row'])):
    $obj = (object) $this->data['row'];
elseif(is_object($this->data['row'])):
    $obj = $this->data['row'];
else:
    echo "Data type not valid";
    die();
endif;

$obj->product_id;
```

I think this will help you.